# Cant get \n to work in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo a string and the string contains "\n" and "\r" in it, but when it executes it still shows the "\n" and "\r".

Here is what I'm doing.

```
$url = 'http://whoiz.herokuapp.com/lookup.json?url=madithouse.com';
$response = file_get_contents($url);
echo $response;
```

It echos every thing as it is, all I want is that everywhere where it has "\n" it goes to new line.

Comment: Are you on the console or a browser.  If Browser (html) replace \n with <br />

Comment: echo nl2br($response);

Comment: @Ignacio The content that url returns, oddly enough, isn't JSON.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams when I decode JSON it only removes the "\n" & "\r" what I want is when there is "\n" it moves to new line

Comment: Ignacio: I'm just getting a simple string. `json_decode()` does nothing to it. This also suggests is isn't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487869/is-this-simple-string-considered-valid-json so I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `nl2br()` doesn't work. If you want output in new line in place of "\n" just replace it with `<br>`.

Like this

```
$url = 'http://whoiz.herokuapp.com/lookup.json?url=madithouse.com';

$response = file_get_contents($url);

echo str_replace("\\n", "<br>", $response);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're outputting to a browser you won't see the new lines (unless you view source). You'd have to use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br).

Answer (score 2):

```
echo nl2br(json_decode($response));
```