# Retrofit with simple json response containing only an integer or a string

Tags: json, retrofit

The rest API that I'm calling just returns an integer: 12.

As far as I know that is a valid json although I would have been happier if I could change the response on the server side to something more canonical. Unfortunately that is not an option for me.

Is there a way to use Retrofit to handle that response too?

**EDIT**

See: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487869/is-this-simple-string-considered-valid-json) and the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)

So it seems the new spec allows to use simple string or integer as a json Text

Comment: Right. That's exactly what I said in my comment: "It's a valid JSON fragment. It is not a valid JSON document."

Comment: what about the part "JSON has been specified more generally in ECMA-404,". Do you mean that ECMA-404 is not used for the json in rest APIs?

Comment: Looks like they've finally updated the actual definition of JSON to get rid of that confusion: [From the more recent RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-2): *"A JSON text is a serialized value.  Note that certain previous specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an array."* So they did away with that distinction, which is great. A **lot** of tools will be using the old definition, though.

Comment: I **do** wish Crockford would pick one definitive place and stick with it. ECMA or (better) IETF, but not *both*. Or if he insists on both, keep them *both* up to date. But then, crockford and I see things differently in several ways... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do it: just use Integer as a template parameter for the `RestCallback`:

```
new RestCallback<Integer>() {...}
```