# Why do I get [Object, object] returned instead of a string?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**I want the success function to pick up the string it should receive from the PHP file.**

The PHP complains "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be a resource, boolean given instead". I assume this is why the success function does not fire.

What am I doing wrong?

**The jQuery:**

```
var string = "something to be inserted";
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {toBeInserted: string.toLowerCase()},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // some code that is to work with data
    }
});
```

**The PHP:**

```
include 'serverStuff.php';
// A separate file with $con defined in it. Assume this works.

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);

// inserts the $_POST['toBeInserted'] into the database just fine

// assume the following are defined: 
// (string) $user_name, (string) $now, (string) $statement

$sql=("SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_name=$user_name AND date=$now AND statement = $statement");
$result=mysql_query($sql, $con);

if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $new_id = (int) $row['id'];
}

mysql_close($con);

echo json_encode($new_id.'_'.$now);
```

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` instead, the console will print objects as [Object, object] if you just print the object itself.

Comment: Done. this is the log: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"\"67_18:52:54 21-8-2015\"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

Answer (score 2):

Strings need to be escaped in SQL:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_name='$user_name' AND date='$now' AND statement = '$statement'"
```

It says "boolean given" because by [the specification](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) `false` is returned if there is an error. (Also consider heeding the deprecation note in the documentation)

Comment: Escaped them, and got a different response text this time:
""66_18:49:55 21-8-2015"". Yes, double double quotes. These come from the DB though, so that much is working now.

Comment: @VHK That's good, that means it's working, right? `66` is the id of the row?

Comment: It is reaching the database, yes, but the jQuery does not pick up the returned object as a string, so the follow up code is not able to work. Yvesmancera asked me to log the object stringified: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"\"67_18:52:54 21-8-2015\"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}. Does this tell you anything I'm missing? And yes: the 66/67/and so on are the concatenated ID's.

Comment: @VHK The issue is because [a string is not valid json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487869/is-this-simple-string-considered-valid-json). See Martin's answer.

Comment: That does make sense, but passing on a string would require the ajax datatype to be 'html' then, correct?

Comment: I would just omit `dataType` and echo the plain string.

Answer (score 0):

For the double double quotes problem use this:

```
echo json_encode(array('result' => $new_id.'_'.$now));
```

And data.result in JS

Comment: What is undefined, data or data.result? Your php file is in UTF-8?

Comment: data.result is undefined. and yes its in utf8.

Comment: Hmm. And how data looks like? Try with some static data. array('result' => "some text") if it works, then something wrong with the concatenated data.

Comment: Sorry for my absence, Martin. I had to eat. I did what you asked and got this in the console.log: Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "test", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}. So it clearly does get passed, but not in a way the success function can pick up the string and work with it.

Comment: responseText: "test". in my opinion you'd like to use arrays. What happens when you try with echo json_encode(array('result' => "test")) ? And what is typeof data in this case in success?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'm still not sure what causes the problem, but the workaround is the following:

- switched the ajax function's datatype from 'json' to 'html';
- changed the echo(json_encode("string")) to just echo("string");
- picked up the string in the success function as follows:

The code:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);
    }
});
```