# JSON.stringify() result when input is single value

Tags: javascript, json

The `JSON.stringify()` method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON

```
console.log(JSON.stringify('a'));
//produce "a"
console.log(JSON.stringify(1));
//produce 1
console.log(JSON.stringify(true));
//produce true
```

but according to the definition these are not JSON

```
"a"
1
true
```

JSON definition is showing below

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
>   realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>   list, or associative array.
>
> An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

my question is `JSON.stringify()` not producing JSON when input above values why is that ?

Comment: What would be a expected result for you? which name would receive those values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The **JSON.stringify()** method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON
>   string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is
>   specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a
>   replacer array is specified.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

"*my question is JSON.stringify() not producing JSON when input above values why is that?*"

These are all Valid JSON syntax representing JSON value:

```
"a"
1
true
{}
[]
```

**Check this:**

```
JSON.parse('"foo"'); // returns "foo"
JSON.parse(1); // returns 1
JSON.parse(true); // returns true
JSON.parse('{}'); // returns {}
JSON.parse('[]');  // returns []
```

For more clarification this check these answers:

[Is this simple string considered valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487869/is-this-simple-string-considered-valid-json)

[What is the minimum valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json)

Comment: is these values "a",1,true are valid json strings