# Why java.lang.String cannot converted into JSONObject in android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am working on Login page and data receiving by server.Here IP, username and password is Entered by user. When IP is correct so he is checked the username and password.After that he is receiving the `JSON` message.Here, result is saved the ""User exists"" and i am checking the "User exists".

When i am tried to convert in `JSONObject` so he gives the error.....
[here is the error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su4bV.png)

> JSON Response: "User Exists"

**MainActivity.java**

```
  private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return GET(urls[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);
            if(jsonResponse.equals("User exists")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Login Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"User does not exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
12-27 10:53:20.662 507-572/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: [1,482,836,000,662 ms] noteScanstart no scan source uid -1
12-27 10:53:21.375 6641-6662/com.example.anew.addbtnontitlebar D/result: "User exists"
12-27 10:53:21.376 6641-6641/com.example.anew.addbtnontitlebar D/error: Value User exists of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
12-27 10:53:23.168 507-572/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: [1,482,836,003,168 ms] noteScanEnd no scan source onTime=0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject)

Comment: No Duplication of JSONException

Comment: try  jsonResponse.toString()..equals("User exists")

Comment: `JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);` remove this line and check directly from `result' like `if(result.equals("User exists"))`. If server returns only this text.

Comment: i dnt understand can u explain it @K

Comment: no when i am remove this line and directly check in if and else loop so, result=""User exists"" and here is given "User exists"................@AnkitaShah

Comment: http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.String- see this link

Comment: @Himanshu Srivastava post your json response that you get

Comment: ya..i know that solution bt that"s not worked........@IntelliJShivam

Comment: @Himanshu Srivastava it is not a valid json  you get only a string value

Comment: please post your response here first

Comment: @HimanshuSrivastava You don't need to convert your response in Json Object. Your response in String so Just compare your response as this way  `if(result.equals("User exists"))` .

Comment: @Charuka json response "User exists"

Comment: ya i got a only json value and he is in double quotes...."User exists"@Charuka

Comment: @Himanshu Srivastava see my answer

Comment: @HimanshuSrivastava Is it resolved?

Comment: @KNeerajLal.......No buddiee still i am facing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  get a json response but its in **Invalid** format, its a string value

To identify its in the valid format you can use http://jsonlint.com/ or something similar.Just paste your response and check it

if its in a valid json format it should be like this

```
{
    "status": "user exists"
}
```

If you had a response like above you can do this;

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);
String status = jsonResponse .getString("status");
```

We catch String using the key, now you don't have any key. You have only a String value.So there is no point of passing that value to a `JSONObject`

so you can do this or ask for a better response form the developer who returns that responce;

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result!= null){
              if (result.equals("User exists")){
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"User exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                   else{
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }
              }
    }
```

Comment: i am chacked JSON response on URL and this is valid and i am follow your way to solving the problem but problem is not solved...................

Comment: @Himanshu Srivastava if you get only something like this "User Exists" it is not valid!!!!!!!!! check all the people who have commented on it and what they say. check my valid json example.

Comment: @Himanshu Srivastava read here  >http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487869/is-this-simple-string-considered-valid-json

Comment: @Himanshu Srivastava in your onPostExecute add a log and print what is your result and see what do you receive

Comment: @Himanshu Srivastava Print that result you get in onPostExcute and post it

Comment: @Himanshu Srivastava  its saying the same thing i can only help you if you put a Log / sys.out and show the result to me.like this `protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        System.out.println("String Result >:" +result);
// other your code
    }`

Run your app and check whats the result value you get there it will print in your log search using "String Result"

Comment: @Himanshu Srivastava or try what i said ..`@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result!= null){
              if (result.equals("User exists")){
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"User exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                   else{
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }
              }
    }` and post the log if there is any error

Comment: String Result >:" +result---""User exists"" when i am debugging it is show on String Result after that he no error show

Comment: @Himanshu Srivastava good then use the method that i gave you for your onPostExcute and see "User exists" Toast gets printed :) do not add other codes in it'

Answer (score 0):

You can access JSON values with key value pairs. so you need to obtain a key from JSON data and compare with values.

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result); 
String jsonKey=jsonResponse.getString("result");
if(jsonKey.equeal("User exists"))
     {
       //do you stuff
    }
```

Comment: No.....Error:----.org.json.JSONException: Value User exists of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject....@Maaz Patel