# Java Jersey JSON service doesn't return quoted string?

Tags: java, json, jersey

Here is a simple Web Service written using Jersey

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Object interpretationJson() {                        
    String o = "a simple string";       
    return o;
}
```

The response for this is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 15
Date: Mon, 02 Oct 2017 23:18:14 GMT

a simple string
```

Shouldn't the string in the response body be quoted? I don't believe this is valid JSON. Shouldn't the response be:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 15
Date: Mon, 02 Oct 2017 23:18:14 GMT

"a simple string"
```

This caused me a bit of confusion. I originally thought the problem was on the client side, but now I think the problem is the string returned from Jersey is not valid JSON - [C# Parsing json that may have simple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534008/c-sharp-parsing-json-that-may-have-simple-types)

Comment: Why? To get a quoted string, escape and add another set of quotes. If you will return a proper json, instead of just string, then value of field will be properly quoted

Comment: The serializer should properly serialize the object being returned. The string without quotes is not valid JSON. This is a simplified example. In the actual code the object "o" is sometimes a simple string, but sometimes is a more complex object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quote attributed to Jackson's developer (Tatu Saloranta / cowtowncoder) about why a simple string is treated this way.

> This is not the reason String is declared untouchable. Rather, choice is
>   between:
>
> Write input String as JSON String, i.e. surround it with double-quotes
>   and escape necessary characters, or
>
> Write String exactly as-is, assuming user wanted to produce exactly that
>   output (presumable hand-encoded JSON).
>
> Since there is no metadata to tell what is user's intention, Jackson is
>   being conservative and using latter choice.
>   This is also prudent considering that JSON Specification only considers
>   JSON Objects and JSON Arrays as valid JSON content -- so strictly speaking,
>   returning a JSON String would produce invalid JSON anyway.

[Referenced issue...](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/231)

"Untouchable" is Jackson's term for a type that will be returned exactly as is.

You can easily return a string with quotes if you want to and there are several ways to do it. But that was not your question, I think.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a recommend way to wrap the untouchable string in quotes? or is something like the following good enough:     Object o = getObjectFromSomewhere();
if (o instanceof String) {
  String s = String.format("\"%s\"", (String)o);
  return s;
}
else {
  return o;
}

Answer (score -1):

```
public class TestGetterSetter{

private String name ;

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name ;
}


public String getName(String name){
    return this.name ;
}}
```

> Using this POJO class Set the value and return this POJO Class Object