# ASP.NET server not sending httpresponse to ajax post call after file save

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im making a jquery ajax post call, and the .success method is being called, but the response data is empty.

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/MediaUploader/fileUpload',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            //Data 
        })
```

The success function is called, but the data is empty.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload() {
    //code
    file.SaveAs(pathToSave);
    return Json(str_image);
```

When called, the response is empty:
[image: no response]

However, commenting out the file.SaveAs, or returning before it, causes the respond to go through:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload() {
    //code
    //file.SaveAs(pathToSave);
    return Json(str_image);
```

[image: yes response]

When debugging, the file.SaveAs doesn't throw any exceptions, and in both cases the return is reached. Also, this problem only is occurring on the remote. On local host both versions work fine.

The response doesnt go through only after the file.SaveAs on remote server.

Comment: what is `file` here?

Comment: It&#39;s an HttpPostedFile containing an image. I should mention when called the file is successfully uploaded to the server

Comment: hmm.. not entirely certain, try changing your `ActionResult` to `JsonResult` and run your scenario again.

Comment: was actually surprised to see this is valid Json text response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487869/is-this-simple-string-considered-valid-json .. I suppose I'm still pre 2014 on this :P

Comment: Response is still empty, except it just shows {} now

Comment: did you check the directory permission you are saving in(in remote server)? it should have write permission for your app pool user

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, it was a problem with directory permissions.

(weird, i didnt think it's an issue because the files were being uploaded successfully anyway)

Comment: You should have a try-catch block to wrap your code to capture any exception and send out a "success" or "failure" response to your ajax call. Another point is to capture the ajax error and write into the console: failure: function () { console.log("Error in ajax call"); }