# Java backend returns a String but Angular frontend doesn't accept it

Tags: angular, typescript, jakarta-ee

What I want to do: Frontend sends username and password to the backend. Backend checks it, generates a random string, and sends back that string to the frontend. Frontend saves that string to localStorage.

In the backend:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String login(String credentials){
    return this.service.login(credentials);

}
```

`this.service.login` returns a string if username and password in `credentials` is OK or returns `null` if not.

In the frontend:

```
public login(username: string, password: string ){
return this.http.post<string>(this.authUrl, JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password}), this.getHeaders())
.pipe(
  tap(
    (token:string) => {
      if(token){
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken',token);
        console.log(`Successful login for username =${username} with password=${password} and token=${token}` );
      } else {
        console.log(`Login failed for username =${username} with password=${password} and token=${token}`);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

}

```
getHeaders(): {headers: HttpHeaders } {
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders(
    {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'responseType': 'text'
    }
  )     
};
return httpOptions;
```

}

If I try to login with wrong username and password, this gets logged: `Login failed for username =something with password=something and token=null` So the returning null part works, But if I send the correct username and password, I get this error:

```
ERROR
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/login", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token M in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "MTMyOTUz"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/login"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/login"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

So it has some JSON.parse problem? Does it expect a JSON so doesn't know what to do with a string? What's a solution to this?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487869/is-this-simple-string-considered-valid-json

Comment: Does your other routes work fine ? Try to add  `Accept: 'application/json'` to your headers.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by other routes, but for example listing users is served by localhost:8080/users and it works fine. I'll try adding that to the headers

Comment: Adding that to the headers just threw me an error 406 (Not Acceptable)

Comment: After a quick search, you may fix the issue by replacing your header responseType by : `'responseType': 'text' as 'json'`

Comment: I tried it but it did not help unfortunately, it gave the same error as originally.

Comment: Your question is not related to Angular, I think that Angular is trying to parse your back-end response which is not a JSON. How are you returning the response from your API ?

Comment: I wanted to return a string, because I only wanted to return a single word so I thought that would be the easiest solution.

Comment: Similar issue here, but I'm actually getting "406 OK"... really bizarre. No amount of tweaking in Angular's headers seems to fix it, and when I do the same request with wget it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I didn't know how to get this work with `string`, so I ended up using `json` instead. So in `this.service.login`:

```
JsonObject tokenJson = new JsonObject();
tokenJson.addProperty("token", token);
return tokenJson;
```

then:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public JsonObject login(String json){
    return this.service.login(json);
}
```

In the frontend changed return type from `string` to `object`and get my token like this:

```
var tokenObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(token));
localStorage.setItem('accessToken',tokenObject.token);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default httpclient parses json. For telling it that in return text will come as response you need to use the syntax below.

this.httpClient.request('GET', 'url, {responseType:'text'});