# Curl request to ansible playbook

Tags: json, curl, ansible

Sample curl request.

```
curl -X POST \
  --data '"test connection"' \
  -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic asdfasdf' \
  dns.com/end
```

Now, I'd like to send exactly the same message using curl ansible playbook.

```
---
- name: "Send test"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Send test
      uri:
        url: dns.com/end
        method: POST
        src: '"test connection"'
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Content-type: "application/json"
          Authorization: "Basic asdfasdf"
```

I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the [`body`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html#parameter-body) parameter instead of [`src`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html#parameter-src). Also, the header should be `Content-Type` instead of `Content-type`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add `src` is used when you want to submit the data from a file.
Solution will look something like

```
tasks:
    - name: Send test
      uri:
        url: dns.com/end
        method: POST
        body: "test connection"
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          Authorization: "Basic asdfasdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned body format as `json` and you are not passing any body to it. 
You body.json file should contain something like this:

```
{
"name": "test connection"
}
```

and also you can mention status_code=201 for POST method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7487892/3966682 - a string is also valid JSON.