# Raise exceptions over REST/JSON - Delphi RAD Server

Tags: rest, delphi, error-handling

In my project, there is a RAD Server that handles access to an MSSQL Database. The client fires CRUD operations via REST to that Server, the Server handles the messages.

Now there is a field in a table that is configured as "unique index". When I try to create a row with an existing value in that field, I get a `ekUKViolated` error message. My question is, how can I pass the error object (not the Message) inside my RAD Server to my client via the REST response? In the REST client, I only get an invalid typecasting error.

Response Code looks like that:

```
try
  ...
except
  on e: Exception do
  begin
    AResponse.StatusCode := 400;
    AResponse.Body.SetValue(TJSONString.Create(e.Message + ' - ' + e.ClassName), True);
    Exit;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The O in "JSON" stands for "object". Everything must either be an object or at least an array - but you only create a JSON string. Hence, it's not valid JSON. Where's the JSON you respond with for HTTP status 200?

Comment: @AmigoJack [Is this simple string considered valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487869/is-this-simple-string-considered-valid-json).

Comment: @AmigoJack my 200 Response works. There I use a Object, but I don't want to write super specific Code for Error Handeling. I would like sort of Convert my Exception Object into JSON and on the Client Side convert it back into Exception so I can handle Usermessages in GUI.

Comment: Send the error message and then the client can use the message to create an exception. Don't try to recreate the exact same exception object.