# API design for an endpoint which receives a single field information?

Tags: api, rest

I’m reviewing my colleague’s code. He created an endpoint for receiving the client’s feedback from a like/dislike button. He designed the API this way:

- it is accessible at`{{url}}/great_new_feature/feedback`;
- it accepts `POST` requests only ;
- Request body should be strictly one of those (binary option):
  `{"feedback": "Not Satisfied"}` and `{"feedback": "Satisfied"}`

I find all of this overly complicated and redundent. So here’s my (two-parts) question:

- Could we not have an endpoint that receives only a single string (`like` / `dislike`), without having it encapsulated in a JSON object ? Is it still a RESTful design? ([This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7487892/9450152) suggests that a string is considered valid JSON)
- Isn’t it a code smell to have a REST endpoint that receives only a single-field information (and, in this case, actually a binary one: true/false)? If so, how should I correct that?

Comment: Admittedly, any question about design, architecture, clean code, or optimal use of resources, can be seen as opinion-based. Should they all disappear from this site, though ? They are the essence of a developer’s day-to-day job, and they can be compared to objective criteria - performance, generally accepted standards, popularity...

Answer (score 1):

> Could we not have an endpoint that receives only a single string (like / dislike), without having it encapsulated in a JSON object ? Is it still a RESTful design? (This post suggests that a string is considered valid JSON)

Yes, you can.  There is no rule that says that a request payload must be an object, or even that a request payload must be JSON.  On the web, many request payloads are `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` key value pairs.

The trade off is that you can extend the schema of an object by adding more "optional" fields, without breaking backwards compatibility.

---

> Isn’t it a code smell to have a REST endpoint that receives only a single-field information (and, in this case, actually a binary one: true/false)?

Yes - in the sense that a "smell" indicates that there *might* be a problem somewhere (see https://wiki.c2.com/?CodeSmell ).

There's nothing wrong with having a document that has but a single field of information in it.

Similarly, there's nothing wrong with making such a document available via the web; there's nothing wrong with supporting changes to that document from the web.

Things get a little bit suspicious when you send edits to one resource expecting the effects to show up somewhere else.  For example, if we are submitting

```
POST /api/great_new_feature/feedback
```

In the expectation that it will change what we see when we

```
GET /api/great_new_feature
```

Then that deserves further review, because it impedes the general purpose [cache invalidation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cache-19#section-4.4) mechanism built into HTTP.  If you are giving up something that is "free", then you better be sure that you are being compensated.  In a code review, I would expect to find a [decision record](https://cognitect.com/blog/2011/11/15/documenting-architecture-decisions) documenting the investigation and its findings.

---

> I’m not sure I understand the last paragraph about cache invalidation. Is it specific to an API expecting a single field of information ?

No.  HTTP message semantics are part of its [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5) -- all resources understand messages the same way.

---

> And what is a generally accepted solution to this problem? (I see that the whole website I work on has a Cache-Control: no-store policy)

Ensure that requests that modify information use the same target URI as the requests that read information.

```
POST /collection
```

Is a popular choice for introducing new items into a collection because (in part) we expect that the introduction of the new item *also* changes the representation of the collection itself (typically with a link to the new item).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I’m not sure I understand the last paragraph about cache invalidation. Is it specific to an API expecting a single field of information ? It seems to apply to any `POST` request. And what is a generally accepted solution to this problem? (I see that the whole website I work on has a `Cache-Control: no-store` policy)